# How to use Tailwind CSS with React and module.scss?

Tags: reactjs, sass, tailwind-css, vite

I made the assembly "Vite + React + Tailwind CSS + SCSS".

Before, I used to work with Tailwind CSS classes in React and used this syntax:

```js
    <header className="header flex">
      <img className="h-50 w-full" src="/src/assets/image-0.png" alt="image" />
    </header>
```

I imported several classes from SCSS files and used some classes from Tailwind CSS in my JSX files, which worked fine.

Now I am using `module.scss` for my SCSS files like this:

```js
    import cn from 'classnames';
    import classes from '../scss/style.module.scss';
    const Header = () => {
      return (
        <header className={cn(classes.header, 'flex')}>
          <img className="h-50 w-full" src="/src/assets/image-0.png" alt="image" />
        </header>
      );
    };
    export default Header;
```

Now I'm running into a problem where my classes from Tailwind CSS no longer work. The classes are in the HTML file, but are empty, as if Tailwind CSS has stopped defining them.

### Here are some files from my project:

**Main.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.jsx**

```js
import cn from 'classnames';
import classes from './scss/style.module.scss';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Profile from './components/Profile';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className={cn(classes.root)}>
      <Header />
      <Navbar />
      <Profile />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**style.module.scss (the main file for my styles)**

```scss
// sass tools
@import 'utilities/variables', 'utilities/fonts', '/node_modules/rfs/scss', 'utilities/functions', 'utilities/mixins';
// global styles
@import 'normalize.css', 'base/typography';
// Added Tailwind directives
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
// layout
@import 'layout/grid';
// components / widgets
@import 'components/button';
// pages specific styles
@import 'pages/home';
```

### This is what my assembly looks like:

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "mt-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --open",
    "serve": "vite --host --port 8080 --cors --open",
    "build": "vite build",
    "builder": "vite builder",
    "preview": "vite preview --open",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rfs": "^9.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@swc-node/jest": "^1.6.2",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^4.0.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "postcss-scss": "^4.0.6",
    "postcss-syntax": "^0.36.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "prettier-plugin-style-order": "^0.2.2",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "stylelint": "^15.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-idiomatic-order": "^9.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier-scss": "^0.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^7.0.1",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.4.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "vite": "^4.1.4",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy';
import viteSvgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    viteSvgr({ exportAsDefault: true }),
    legacy({
      targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11'],
    }),
  ],
  base: './',
});
```

**tailwind.config.сjs**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}', './index.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
};
```

**postcss.config.cjs**

```js
module.exports = {
  syntax: 'postcss-scss',
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: './tailwind.config.сjs'
    },
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
};
```

**.stylelintrc.json**

```js
{
  "plugins": ["stylelint-scss", "@namics/stylelint-bem"],
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss",
    "stylelint-config-idiomatic-order",
    "stylelint-config-prettier-scss"
  ],
  "rules": {
  "font-family-name-quotes": null,
  "plugin/stylelint-bem-namics": {
      "patternPrefixes": [],
      "helperPrefixes": []
    },
    "scss/at-rule-no-unknown": [
      true,
      {
        "ignoreAtRules": ["tailwind", "layer"]
      }
    ],
    "selector-class-pattern": null

  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "customSyntax": "postcss-scss",
      "files": ["**/*.scss"]
    },
    {
      "customSyntax": "@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js",
      "files": ["**/*.jsx", "**/*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "function-name-case": [
          "lower",
          {
            "ignoreFunctions": ["/.*/"]
          }
        ],
        "selector-class-pattern": [
          "^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(-[a-z0-9]+)*((__([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(-[a-z0-9]+)*)?(--([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(-[a-z0-9]+)*)?)$"
        ],
        "value-keyword-case": [
          "lower",
          {
            "ignoreFunctions": ["/.*/"],
            "ignoreKeywords": ["/.*/"],
            "ignoreProperties": ["/.*/"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**.prettierrc.json**

```js
{
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "plugins": ["./node_modules/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"],
  "printWidth": 200,
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5"
}
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```js
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest/globals": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "jsx-a11y",
    "jest",
    "import",
    "unused-imports"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "import/order": [
          "error",
          {
            "groups": [
              "builtin",
              "external",
              "internal",
              [
                "parent",
                "sibling"
              ],
              "index",
              "object",
              "type"
            ],
            "pathGroups": [
              {
                "pattern": "./**/**\\.css",
                "group": "type",
                "position": "after"
              }
            ],
            "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": [
              "builtin"
            ],
            "alphabetize": {
              "order": "asc",
              "caseInsensitive": true
            },
            "newlines-between": "always",
            "warnOnUnassignedImports": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "warn",
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": "warn",
    "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions": "warn",
    "jsx-quotes": [
      "error",
      "prefer-double"
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "react/function-component-definition": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "warn",
    "semi": "error"
  }
}
```

**.editorconfig**

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: https://EditorConfig.org

# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
max_line_length = 80
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = 0
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

# Matches multiple files with brace expansion notation
# Set default charset
[*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,py}]
charset = utf-8

[*.py]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

# Tab indentation (no size specified)
[Makefile]
indent_style = tab

# Matches the exact files either package.json or .travis.yml
[{package.json,.travis.yml}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `*.module.scss` files only inside your components.

For global styles use regular `*.scss` files - create one `global.scss` file and put all external imports (such as tailwind) there. Then import that file inside your `index.tsx` or `App.tsx` like that:

```
import './global.scss';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll definitely try it later and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

First create global scss file for your project and import tailwind css files in to it,

Then configure vite config file to load global scss file automatically

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "./src/assets/styles/Global.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Watch this video for more details

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u_xszhR5XY&t=30s